# Cakephp 3.9 Multiple Associations with the Same Table

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I am working on Cakephp 3.9 and I have 3 tables in my application.

```
CREATE TABLE `leads` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `created_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `clients` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `lead_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `lead_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There is a one-to-one relation between the Leads, Clients, and Contacts tables.

I also have a Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

... and a leads_users table

```
CREATE TABLE `leads_users` (
 `lead_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `user_type` enum('Opener','Closer') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

In my application, the users can be associated with the leads as Openers and Closers. There can be multiple openers and multiple closers for a lead. I have defined my models as below:

```
class LeadsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasOne('Contacts');

        $this->hasOne('Clients');

        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'className' => 'Users'
        ])
            ->setConditions(['LeadsUsers.user_type' => 'Opener'])
            ->setProperty('openers');

        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'className' => 'Users'
        ])
            ->setConditions(['LeadsUsers.user_type' => 'Closer'])
            ->setProperty('closers');
    }
}

class ClientsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Leads');
    }

}

class ContactsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Leads');
    }

}

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Leads');
    }

}
```

Now in the Leads controller, I am trying to find all the leads, their contacts, clients, openers, and closers by using the below line of code.

```
$result = $this->Leads->find('all')->contain(['Contacts', 'Clients', 'Users']);
```

With this, I am getting the closers but not the openers. In the LeadsTable, if I comment out the closers association then I am getting the openers. So looks like the second association is overwriting the first one.

If I change the LeadsTable association to below:

```
class LeadsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasOne('Contacts');

        $this->hasOne('Clients');

        $this->belongsToMany('Openers', [
            'className' => 'Users'
        ])
            ->setConditions(['LeadsUsers.user_type' => 'Opener'])
            ->setProperty('openers');

        $this->belongsToMany('Closers', [
            'className' => 'Users'
        ])
            ->setConditions(['LeadsUsers.user_type' => 'Closer'])
            ->setProperty('closers');
    }

}
```

I am getting the below error:

> The Users association is not defined on Leads.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you have to change your controller query as well.

```
$result = $this->Leads->find('all')->contain(['Contacts', 'Clients', 'Closers','Openers']);
```

Comment: Thanks @Syan for your reply. I get below error with this.

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'LeadsUsers.closer_id' in 'on clause'

SELECT LeadsUsers.lead_id AS `Closers_CJoin__lead_id`, LeadsUsers.user_id AS `Closers_CJoin__user_id`, LeadsUsers.user_type AS `Closers_CJoin__user_type`, Closers.id AS `Closers__id`, Closers.username AS `Closers__username`, Closers.password AS `Closers__password` FROM users Closers INNER JOIN leads_users LeadsUsers ON Closers.id = (LeadsUsers.closer_id) WHERE (LeadsUsers.lead_id in (:c0,:c1) AND LeadsUsers.user_type = :c2)

Comment: It is assuming a different join key, closer_id. I tried specifying the foreignKey as lead_id and bindingKey as user_id in the Leads model association, but it didn't work.

Comment: It's working only for one association with the Users table. The moment I add another "contain" with the same table, it either throws an error, overwrites the previous contain data, or show both as blank.

Comment: have you tried the querybuilder? It may save you the time to find this error

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up changing my database a bit and that fixed it.

```
CREATE TABLE `leads_openers` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `lead_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `opener_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `leads_closers` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `lead_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `closer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and then I changed my models like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class OpenersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Leads', [
            'joinTable' => 'leads_openers',
        ]);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ClosersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Leads', [
            'joinTable' => 'leads_closers',
        ]);
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class LeadsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsToMany('Openers', [
            'joinTable' => 'leads_openers',
        ])
            ->setProperty('openers');

        $this->belongsToMany('Closers', [
            'joinTable' => 'leads_closers',
        ])
            ->setProperty('closers');
    }
}
```

and then in the controller, I am doing this:

```
$leads = $this->Leads->find('all')
                ->where(['Leads.status IN' => $search_condition_lead])
                ->contain(['Contacts', 'Openers', 'Closers']);
```